# How to complete combineLatest?

Tags: rxjs, rxjs6, rxjs-observables

I use `combineLatest` to get latest values from each observables:

```
combineLatest$ = combineLatest(_block$, _field$);
    combineLatest$.subscribe(() => {
      console.log("Completed...");
    });
```

Then I have another observable that works until `forkJoin$` sends data:

```
of(true).pipe(delay(1000), takeUntil(combineLatest$)).subscribe(() => console.log());
```

How to complete `combineLatest$`? And should I unsubscribe from `of()` or it will be destroyed automaticaly?

Comment: So, I have tied to await 1 second and then if not response from server from all requests I should do operation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. `takeUntil` will run teardown logic for you. Seems you're confusing the `forkJoin` semantics with `combileLatest`, they are quite different. In your particular case `forkJoin$` has not the [true forkJoin semantics](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/forkjoin); I guess you have to complete both `_block$` and `_field$` in order for `combineLatest` to complete.

Comment: Sorry it is type of variables I use `combineLatest`. Fixed

Comment: Yes, how to complete `combineLatest$` in advance?

Comment: I need await when all observables on the page wuill be completed, should I use forkJoin?

Comment: So, how to complete `_block$` then and `_field$`?

Comment: @Jony you can either complete them manually (by calling `complete()`) or use some completable operator. You have to provide more code for us to figure one which option is more appropriate. Anyway, completion does depend upon `_block$` and `_field$` instances.

Comment: @Jony P.S. Yes, `forkJoin` is the choice if you'd like to run all the observables **in pseudo-parallel** and await for their completeness. In case you rely on unbound stream (i.e., instance that never completes), your `forkJoin` will never complete too.

Comment: Observable has no `complete()`

Comment: @Jony, just a typo, I meant `Observer`. See https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/observable for examples how to `complete` manually if you'd like to do it in manual fashion.